# Where do I need to select the to be shown in the RecylerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Probably the question is not as easy to understand as I wish.

I created a RecylerView which holds objects of the type `c_TakeTimeObjects` from an ArrayList. These objects have special information about themselves, like a Date.

So there could be, lets say 20, of these Objects in an ArrayList and what I want to do is to just show the ones which "Date" value is matching with the Date value shown in a TextView above the RecylerView.

If the TextView shows "12.07.2016" only the elements from the ArrayList which have their "Date" Value set to "12.07.2016" should be shown.
If there aren't any Objects with these "Date" value the List should be empty.

To try this out, I made the following:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull c_ViewHolder c_viewHolder, int i) {
        c_TakeTimeObjects currentItem = c_takeTimeObjects.get(i);
        if(currentItem.getiActivityDate().equals("12.06.2016")) {
            c_viewHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getiImageResource());
            c_viewHolder.mCardview.setLayoutParams(new CardView.LayoutParams((int) (currentItem.getiActivityTime() * fDISPLAYFACTOR), CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            c_viewHolder.mCardview.setCardBackgroundColor(currentItem.getiImageColor());
        }
    }
```

This is the content of the ArrayList:

```
 private void createExampleList() {
        StatusImageList = new ArrayList<>();
        StatusImageList.add(new c_TakeTimeObjects(c_GlobalValues.iBreakMode,((int) (idefaultRestMinutesEarly)), "12.07.2016",this));
        StatusImageList.add(new c_TakeTimeObjects(c_GlobalValues.iWorkingMode, ((int) (idefaultWorkingMinutes)), "12.07.2016",this));
        StatusImageList.add(new c_TakeTimeObjects(c_GlobalValues.iBreakMode, ((int) (idefaultBreakMinutes)), "12.07.2016",this));
        StatusImageList.add(new c_TakeTimeObjects(c_GlobalValues.iWorkingMode, ((int) (idefaultWorkingMinutes)),"12.07.2016",this));
        StatusImageList.add(new c_TakeTimeObjects(c_GlobalValues.iBreakMode, ((int) (idefaultRestMinutesLate)),"12.07.2016",this));
    }
```

See difference "12.06.2019" to "12.07.2019".

I thought the RecylerView is empty now, but in fact it adds 5 white elements without any content. Did I ask for the Date at the wrong method or where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecyclerView adapters don't have a notion of filtering data.  That's something you need to handle on your own.  One thing you could do is pass your RecyclerView adapter your list AFTER filtering it.

For example:

```
List<c_TakeTimeObjects> statusImageList = createExampleList();
Iterator<c_TakeTimeObjects> iter = statusImageLists.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   if (iter.next().getActivityDate() != /* ... */) {
       iter.remove()
   }
}

// Set data, constructor, or whatever method you use to set list data
adapter.setData(statusImageList);
```

Adapters are very good at exactly one thing: rendering views for items in a list.  No filtering or transforming included otherwise.

Comment: I don't need to try this out to know it will work, thanks.
How would you implement that in the case with switching the date you want to load new objects?

Comment: I'd implement `setData` inside your adapter to allow updates on-the-go to the recyclerview (perhaps using `DiffUtils`).  I'd keep track of my original list of objects, plus the desired date. When I update the desired date, I'd redo the code in my example with the new date.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this behaviour is expected.

A quick solution would be to hide an element if it does not pass your if-check but there's a style to this approach. Simply doing `itemView.setVisibility(Visibility.GONE)` would not solve this problem. All you need to do is to set the width and the height of the element to zero (thus mimicking non-visibility). You can change your `onBindViewHolder` implementation to this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull c_ViewHolder c_viewHolder, int i) {

    c_TakeTimeObjects currentItem = c_takeTimeObjects.get(i);

    if(currentItem.getiActivityDate().equals("12.06.2016")) {
        c_viewHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getiImageResource());
        c_viewHolder.mCardview.setLayoutParams(new CardView.LayoutParams((int) (currentItem.getiActivityTime() * fDISPLAYFACTOR), CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        c_viewHolder.mCardview.setCardBackgroundColor(currentItem.getiImageColor());
    }

    else {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams param = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) c_viewHolder.getLayoutParams();
        param.height = 0;
        param.width = 0;
        c_viewHolder.setLayoutParams(param);
    }
}
```

This way, the view does not show up if your if-check isn't passed.

I hope this helps. Merry coding!